# Error: ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns

Tags: sqlplus

I have two relational views.

First view:

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW1
AS
SELECT T#,
MAX(DECODE(LEG#,1,DEPARTURE)) ORIGIN,
MAX(DECODE(LEG#,1,DESTINATION)) DESTINATION1
FROM TRIPLEG
WHERE T# IN
(SELECT T# FROM TRIPLEG WHERE LEG# < 3
AND T# IN
(SELECT T# FROM TRIPLEG GROUP BY T#
HAVING COUNT(T#) < 3)
GROUP BY T#)
GROUP BY T#
ORDER BY T#;
```

Second view:

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW2
AS
SELECT T#,
MAX(DECODE(LEG#,2,DESTINATION)) DESTINATION1
FROM TRIPLEG
WHERE T# IN
(SELECT T# FROM TRIPLEG WHERE LEG# < 3
AND T# IN
(SELECT T# FROM TRIPLEG GROUP BY T#
HAVING COUNT(T#) < 3)
GROUP BY T#)
GROUP BY T#
ORDER BY T#;
```

I use
    SELECT * FROM VIEW1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM VIEW2

And I got the error ORA-01789.

What I want to achieve is

```
T#    |       ORIGIN   | DESTINATION1 | DESTINATION2
------------------------------------------------------
1            abc            efg           hij
```

is what I create considered relational views?

Answer (score 11):

Both views must have the same number of columns in order to perform a UNION ALL. Look at Oracle reference: [The UNION ALL, INTERSECT, MINUS Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm)

Answer (score 3):

I think you want an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `UNION ALL`.  Does something like the following help?

```
SELECT v1.T#, v1.ORIGIN, v1.DESTINATION1, v2.DESTINATION2
  FROM VIEW1 v1
 INNER JOIN VIEW2 v2 ON v1.T# = v2.T#
```

(I assume your view `VIEW2` has a column named `DESTINATION2`, not `DESTINATION1` as written above.)

If you dropped the `ORIGIN` column from `VIEW1`, you could then run `SELECT * FROM VIEW1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM VIEW2`, but this would give you the following output:

```
T#    |  DESTINATION1 
---------------------
1     |       efg    
1     |       hij
```

The reason is that `UNION ALL` simply appends rows together, it doesn't merge them.  If `VIEW1` still had its `ORIGIN` column, Oracle wouldn't be able to append the rows to make one set of rows because some rows would have three values in them and others would have two.